# What are some good programs which can be used to rate-limit traffic on a server?

Tags: windows-7, traffic-shaping, bandwidth-control, rate-limiting

We have some applications which **hog network traffic** on one of our servers (Windows 7) at the expense of the other (more important) applications. Is there an easy way to limit the bandwidth usage of this particular application with a program or whatnot? It's essentially streaming videos and we want to throttle it such that it can only use a certain amount of our allotted download bandwidth.

Comment: Windows 7. Server. Houston, we have a problem.

Comment: It's not actually used for hosting anything super serious, it's just a "play with stuff" / test box. :P

Comment: You need to think a bit what you want. Do you want all the connections currently open throttled so no video will work properly? Or deny new incoming connections? Or deny new sessions?

Comment: @anttiR: You know when you're using a bit-torrent client, the application seems to seek out the maximum possible bandwidth available to it with no regard to any other traffic on the system. We don't want that. Some applications (like bit-torrent clients) allow you to set a max download rate, but the application we're using doesn't. The question is, are their applications or router settings that can force this kind of rate-limiting onto the hogging program? I need this done in a way that the streaming videos still render properly, but don't choke the network while they're in progress.

Comment: @stoicfury Thsi will get complicated. This kind of limiting is good for downloads but for videos it will cut down the transfer rates of all streams. It will not be good. You need to calculate the amount of concurrent streams you can fully support and limit concurrent users to this amount.

Comment: We only ever have one user streaming at a time, and it's still enough to choke the 20mbps rate we get... Maybe I'm not understanding?

Comment: My similar question was closed but this one has been okay for 12 years? https://serverfault.com/questions/1157088/what-are-some-good-nginx-rate-limits-for-wordpress-websites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I user Netlimiter 2 for my personal stuff.

http://www.netlimiter.com/

I know they've moved to 3, but I haven't. Its absolutely fantastic for my purposes. You can block/limit inbound and outbound seperately, by application, by port (although I don't think you can just do port filtering...)

Its USD29.99 so will definitely break the bank (If Sam's answer is anything to go by ;).

I don't think I'd recommend it for a genuine server environment, definitely a power user product rather than administrator.

Oh... if you do get hold of 2 for  whatever reason and have problems installing on Win 7 x64, Win 2K compatibility mode has sorted me out.

Comment: +1 I use this on my workstation to slow down specific applications or protocols.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling i'm not going to live that brief episode of finger trouble down....  :-)

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't personally tried it,  someone else I know has recommended [NetPeeker](http://www.net-peeker.com/) to me previously.  Its payware, but at $25 USD, it shouldn't break the bank. And it lets you throttle by application or port (so its doesn't just slow the whole machine down).

Comment: Did you mean *shouldn't* break the bank?

Answer (score 2):

You might find more useful to put a m0n0wall in front of it, or similar device.

Comment: Or tomato/ddwrt/openwrt router with QoS enabled.

Comment: In the same vein as m0n0wall, pfsense and IPCop are good alternatives too. http://www.pfsense.org/ & http://www.ipcop.org/

Answer (score 1):

If it is internet bandwith that your looking to control then you need to look at your perimeter, the edges of your network, the path that data takes in an out. Putting in place a smart firewall will really help to take care of bandwith problems. My personal favorite, ClearOS - formerly know a few years ago as Clark Connect. Clear OS is easy to use, and is *very* effective at restricting 'greedy b*stards' on your network!

The lunch time YouTube crew  now all use just the one computer to watch streams ever since ClearOS went in, and funny thing is, everyone is now more friendly, and shares lunch, Win, Win, and Win! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting the videos using IIS then you can install and configure Bit Rate Throttling.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/148/bit-rate-throttling-configuration-walkthrough/